# How to append corresponding value to the corresponding dom element using for loop jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried looping the ratings and it is displaying all the values to the same dom element. How do i append it to corresponding dom elements.

This is what tried:

HTML:

```
<div class="rating" data-id="0"></div>
<div class="rating" data-id="2.5"></div>
<div class="rating" data-id="1.5"></div>
<div class="rating" data-id="3"></div>
<div class="rating" data-id="4.678"></div>
```

JS:

```
var ratingValue = "", rounded = "";
var ratingCon = $('.rating');
for(var i=0; i<ratingCon.length; i++){
    ratingValue = $(ratingCon[i]).data("id"), rounded = (ratingValue | 0);
  for (var j = 0; j < 5 ; j++) {
  $(".rating").append('<i class="fa '+ ((j < rounded) ? "fa-star" : ((((ratingValue - j) > 0) && ((ratingValue - j) < 1)) ? "fa-star-half-o" : "fa-star-o")) +'" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
}
}
```

[Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/32L669tv/11/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your second `for` loop your call `$(".rating")` though selecting all elements with the className `rating` is ultimately just using the first `.rating` element when you append. If you change `$(".rating")` to `$(ratingCon[i])` it will all work. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/32L669tv/12/.

Comment: @M-S yeah! If this is the correct answer would you mind marking it as such? Thanks!